# Recveived error from phantomjs:ERROR: While rendering, there's is a timeout reached

Tags: highcharts

I have some error while exporting the chart. I am using the exporting.js from Highcharts
Export PNG, JPEG, PDF received the below error. 
Export SVG ok. But can't see the image.

> Oops..,
>
> Something went wrong while converting. recveived error from phantomjs:ERROR: While rendering, there's is a timeout reached

```
  function renderChartPie(divId, chartType, chartTitle, chartCriteria, chartData, categories) {

     var data = jQuery.parseJSON(chartData);
     var cat = jQuery.parseJSON(categories);

     var options = createOptionPie(divId, chartType, chartTitle, chartCriteria, cat);
     options.series = [{
        data : data            
     }];
     var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
  }

  function createOptionPie(divId, chartType, chartTitle, chartCriteria, categories) {
     var options = {
        colors : [ '#2f7ed8', '#0d233a', '#8bbc21', '#910000', '#1aadce', 
                    '#492970', '#f28f43', '#77a1e5', '#c42525', '#a6c96a',
                    '#4572A7', '#AA4643', '#89A54E', '#80699B', '#3D96AE', 
                    '#DB843D', '#92A8CD', '#A47D7C', '#B5CA92' ],
        chart : {
           renderTo : divId,
           type : chartType,
           events: {
                  load: function() {
                      var text = this.renderer.text('<br/>' + chartCriteria, 0, 445).css({
                         fontSize : 9
                      }).add();

                      var image = this.renderer.image('../../theme/50x71.png', 630, 409, 70, 51)
                      .add();
                  }
              }
        },
        credits : {
           enabled : false
        },
        legend : {
           align: 'right',
             verticalAlign: 'middle',
           layout : 'vertical'               
        },
        title : {
           text : chartTitle
        },
        tooltip: {
                 formatter: function() {
                   return this.point.name +': '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0) ;
               }
          },
        xAxis : {
           categories : categories
        },
        yAxis: {
          },
          plotOptions: {
               pie: {
                  allowPointSelect : true,
                  showInLegend : true
               }
           },
        series : []
     };

     return options;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with timeout, because calling function (export) is limited. If problem will still appear, please prepare your own exporting server. Instructions are available here: http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/56-improved-image-export-with-phantomjs